# how to make the output prompt from input() be in color (python)?

Tags: python, colors

Apparently the TA in the lab for my AI course wants the codes submitted to be "Highly Readable" and that we should use colors.

anyway been trying to manipulate color in output texts, changing output text for `print()` is easy, but it's pretty annoying for the `input()` method.
i tried using libraries like [termcolor](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) and [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) but they didn't work.

one method that worked is doing the following:

```
BLACK = '\033[30m'
RED = '\033[31m'
GREEN = '\033[32m'
YELLOW = '\033[33m'
BLUE = '\033[34m'
MAGENTA = '\033[35m'
CYAN = '\033[36m'
WHITE = '\033[37m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
RESET = '\033[0m'

x1 = input(GREEN + "some text in green")
x2 = input(RED + "some text in red")
```

for some reason the code works in random online compiler sites but not on my python shell or in a ipynb cell like in google collab, anyone has any idea?

Comment: *the TA in the lab for my AI course wants the codes submitted to be "Highly Readable" and that we should use colors* - I *think* what they meant is they want you to format your source code properly, and to aid you with that, use an editor which has syntax highlighting.

Comment: That is also how I understand it. So use clear variable names, clear doc-strings, proper comments and follow the conventions as in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: He specifically asked for colored output